# Is it appropriate to report bugs for hardware which is not officially supported?

Tags: drivers, hardware, bug-reporting

According to the official bug reporting guide ([Wiki Page: ReportingBugs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)):

> You should not file a bug if you are:
> [...]
> **Filing a bug against a package not provided by the default, supported Ubuntu repositories:** [...] Typically, what isn't supported is software from a PPA (Personal Package Archive), 3rd party packages, self-compiled software, etc. [...]

Does this apply also to drivers from an unsupported device which are not included in the standard Ubuntu distribution?

E.g. I've got an Acer One 10 S1003 which has a 64bit Intel Atom x5-Z8350 CPU, but a 32bit UEFI. To install Ubuntu on it, it is needed to patch the ISO with a 32bit bootloader (using [this handy tool](https://linuxiumcomau.blogspot.com/2017/06/customizing-ubuntu-isos-documentation.html)). So I think it is *technically* not supported by Ubuntu. After the installation process, everything worked fine (only needed to install a 32bit bootloader on the EFI partition) except my WiFi and Bluetooth Card, the BCM4343A0. After searching the internet, I found [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328001/trouble-activating-the-sdio-broadcom-bcm43430-wifi-chip-on-linux-4-8-0); and it looks like there were missing firmware files. Applied the fix and now everything works flawlessly. Shall I file a bug for things like this?

Thank you for any answer, I hope I'm not missing something here.

**Edit (for the ones who are interested in my specific case):** Thanks for the answer(s) and clarifications. Looked further into it and I think the missing firmware files are issues within the kernel, so the bug should be filed there. I was confused because it was fixed at one time in the kernel (so I thought it was Ubuntu's problem), can't seem to find the according patchcode anymore in today's kernel code - looks like there was a rewrite of the driver or something (if I'm right, don't know anything about kernel development).

Comment: I personally don't think it'll hurt.  If the developer/packager considers it off-topic to what they are doing, it'll get closed as "*Invalid*".  If they can't fix it it'll likely get changed "*Won't fix*". They may point you elsewhere/upstream, but I can't see that it'll hurt, at worst you'll risk the minutes it takes to file the bug, but also may get a solution that will help not just you (*reward*).  My 2c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, if a developer is actively maintaining a software he will be interested in bug reports about it. The page you cite only refers to Ubuntu bug report system and, as it states, "If you are using unsupported software *[= software not supported by Ubuntu developers]*, it is best to contact the maintainers directly. Instructions are generally available on the program maintainer's web site" (italics sentence is mine). That's because a person that doesn't know the software can't fix it (unless he studies the source code - but they probably won't), but the maintainers is usually able to do that quite fast.

In your specific situations, if you have problems with a tool/bootloader/driver that is not developed by Canonical you should contact the tool/bootloader/driver's maintainers and not Ubuntu ones.